# HTTP Error 403: Forbidden when using urllib.request

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I tried to run this code, but all the time I receive the error `HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`.

```
import urllib.request

try:
    url = urllib.request.urlopen('http://google.com/search?q=test')
    headers = {}
    headers['User-Agent'] ='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36' 
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    resp_Data = resp.read()

    savefile = open('newFile.txt', 'w')
    savefile.write(str(resp_Data))
    savefile.close()
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

Could anyone help me in this code, because I couldn't find a solution here?

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
url = urllib.request.urlopen('http://google.com/search?q=test')
```

to

```
url = 'http://google.com/search?q=test'
```

Comment: And there is improper indentation on lines starting with savefile

Comment: @WombatPM But that doesn't seem to the error. Looks like it was a mistake while pasting it here. But still, Thanks.